# How to format JSON: Array of objects, or document containing elements with objects?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, formatting

So I'm currently trying to develop a JSON document which will be easiest to iterate through and access objects from. I will be using underscore, so accessing objects isn't necessarily difficult, but I'm wondering what the best way of going about formatting is - best practices, etc.

Here're the two formats I'm considering: The first is an array

```
{
    "defaultViews" : [
        {
            "name" : "view1",
            "title" : "View 1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "view2",
            "title" : "View 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or, the other way, which is more.... "object oriented"...

```
{
    "defaultViews" : {
        "view1" : {
            "title" : "View 1"
        },
        "view2" : {
            "title" : "View 2"
        }
    }
}
```

So in the first example it's easier to iterate through the objects, whereas in the second example it's easier to access the object directly (`obj.defaultViews.view1`). I suppose this is quite subjective, but again I'm looking for what's hopefully considered a "best practice". Thanks!

Comment: You've answered to your question yourself: "So in the first example it's easier to iterate through the objects, whereas in the second example it's easier to access the object directly (obj.defaultViews.view1)."

Comment: Yes I suppose haha, so there's no real standard for this?

Comment: Exact format generally depends on your goal. Also, second notation is applicable only when keys (`view1`, `view2`) are unique while in first notation there is not such limitation.

Comment: Soliciting opinions about code design belong in http://codereview.stackexchange.com, not here.

Comment: _'more.... "object oriented"'_ - I can't tell if you mean that as a joke, or if you think it somehow follows "object oriented" coding principles? The first way is perfectly fine from an OO point of view. (By the way, you don't iterate through JSON, you parse the JSON and iterate through the resulting object/array.)

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong with using an array in object orientation principles. also the first examples that uses an array is a better approach because what you actually want is an array

Comment: Yes I'm leaning towards this too - just because I do have the option of iteration through the array as opposed to the other way..