# Jackson mapper. Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class ]: missing type id property '' (for POJO property '')

Tags: java, jackson, mapping, deserialization, objectmapper

I am using openapi generator in order to generate my classes

Base class

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  EntityType.CONTAINER
})
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "...")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "structure_type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SonClass1, name = "sonClass1"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SonClass2, name = "sonClass2"),
})
public class MyBaseClass {
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_CONTAINER = "container";
  private String container;
}
```

SonClass1 example

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  NodeType.JSON_PROPERTY_PROPERTIES,
})
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "...")
public class SonClass1 extends MyBaseClass {
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_PROPERTIES = "properties";
  private Map<String, Property> properties = null;
}
```

I am trying to build object using ObjectMapper using mapper.readValue();
Result is exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.MySon1]: missing type id property 'structure_type'
```

Could you please explain me why is that, and what I could do with this? Does it mean I have to add property "structure_type" on each subclass?

Openapi yaml look like this

```
MyBaseClass:
  type: object
  properties:
    container:
      type: string
  discriminator:
    propertyName: structure_type
    mapping:
      sonClass: '#/sonClass1'


sonClass1:
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/MyBaseClass'
  - type: object
    properties:
      properties:
        type: object
        additionalProperties:
          $ref: '#/Property'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My base class should have “structure_type” property, after adding this - everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, json string was not matched with the JAVA object type. I corrected my json string,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this exception by correcting my JSON format. If you have arrays of multiple objects in a class, your JSON format should be nested too. Checkout this link for using correct JSON format [How to format JSON: Array of objects, or document containing elements with objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641463/how-to-format-json-array-of-objects-or-document-containing-elements-with-objec)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error for below pojo class:

[image]

Error
[image]

Resolved this by adding @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "@class") to pojo class
[image]